# AJAX returning only one record

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

My `MySQL` table **`course`** has two records.

```
---------------------------
|     id     |     abc    |
---------------------------
|     1      |   Honours  |
---------------------------
|     2      |   General  |
---------------------------
```

**CourseType**

```
<select class="form-control" name="CourseType" id="CourseType">
    <option value="">Select..</option>
    <option value="Mainstream">Regular/Mainstream Course</option>
    <option value="Vocational">Vocational Course</option>
</select>
```

**My Ajax is as follows...**

```
$("#CourseType").change(function () {

        var CourseType = $(this).val();

        $('#ldr').show();
        //alert(CourseType);
        $.ajax({
            url: 'core/check_course.php',
            data: {'CourseType': CourseType},
            dataType:'json',
            type: "post",
            success: function(data){
                //alert(data);
                console.log(data.length);
                console.log(data);
                var course = $("#course");
                course.html('');
                $.each(data, function(idx, elem){
                    //alert(elem.id);
                    course.append('<option value="'+elem.id+'">'+elem.abc+'</option>');
                    $('#ldr').hide();
                });
            }
        });

    });
```

**check_course.php**

```
$ct = $_POST['CourseType'];

$data = array();
if($ct==='Mainstream'){

$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM course");
while($qry = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
    $data[]=array(
        'id' => $qry['id'],
        'abc' => $qry['abc']
    );
}

} else {

$sql1 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM course WHERE abc='General'");
while($qry1 = mysql_fetch_array($sql1)){
    $data[]=array(
        'id' => $qry1['id'],
        'abc' => $qry1['abc']
    );
}

}
echo json_encode($data);
```

The problem is, it is only showing only one record. It seems, it is not recognizing `if($ct==='Mainstream'){` and executing/fetching only the second `query` i.e. `SELECT * FROM course WHERE abc='General'`.

I have deleted the `if()` statement and tried to execute it. This time it is showing all records.

What should I do ?

Comment: Try: `$(this).find('option:selected').val()`

Comment: Check `$ct` value

Comment: @u_mulder I have checked it. Value is `Mainstream`

Comment: Do a `var_dump($ct);` to see what the exact value is.

Comment: It's obviously not as your `else` branch is working

Comment: @Raphioly-San Tried. Not working.

Comment: @u_mulder I know it is not working therefore asked for solution. So what should I do ?

Comment: Voting to close, this is going nowhere...

Comment: try echoing the comparison $ct==='Mainstream'.  you can also try using strcmp($ct, "Mainstream") == 0

Comment: @Raj I've actually tested your code and it works. Something else isn't working in your config. Please first try any other possibilities that may alter the outcome before posting again. Maybe you have multiple `#CourseType` dropdowns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**MY FAULT**

---

I have changed...

```
$.ajax({
       .....
       type: "post",
```

to `type: "get",` and...

in **`check_course.php`** changed `$ct = $_POST['CourseType'];` to `$ct = $_GET['CourseType'];` and got the result.

[image: XHR Mode]

Thank you [Raphioly-San](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1551749/raphioly-san) for your comment.

> Something else isn't working in your config.

Actually it should be. Because I want to get the result by `passing` a `key value`.

Therefore it is **my fault**.